# Android sort array

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array

how can i sort this array by date or name?

```
String[][] datetable= new String[21][2];

datetable[0][0] = "2011.01.01";
datetable[0][1] = "Name1";
datetable[1][0] = "2011.01.03";
datetable[1][1] = "Name2";
.
.
.
datetable[20][0] = "2011.02.16";
datetable[20][1] = "Name3";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort a two dimensional array based on one column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907683/sort-a-two-dimensional-array-based-on-one-column)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do what the poster linked to, only I wouldn't use `final` so much.

```
Arrays.sort(datetable, new Comparator<String[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String[] entry1, String[] entry2) {
        // Sort by date
        return entry1[0].compareTo(entry2[0]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help: [Sort a two dimensional array based on one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907683/sort-a-two-dimensional-array-based-on-one-column)

Comment: Looks good. I would like to paste some code here how to do that? –

Comment: Thank you! Thats is the simple solution what i was looking for!

Comment: In certain languages there are special letters. In Hungary we have also e.g. Á, which follows letter A. In this sorting procedure words starting with these letters are at the end of the of the array. Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: It's a matter of how you override the "compare" function. In that code example, the "compare" function simply uses the default String.compareTo() to sort strings. The reason you found those words are put to the end is probably because their unicode is bigger than the unicode of any English letters. If you want to put Á right after A, you will need to implement a more sophisticated "compare" function.