# Sorting array of strings

Tags: java, sorting

I am developing a project in android. I have five arrays of type String, with each item in the array related to the respective index of the remaining arrays. Here I need to sort the single array, if I sort, all the respective index should replicate in the proper order as it was present in the sorted array.

Source code:

```
array1 = new String[qrcodelist.size()];
array2 = new String[name.size()];
array3 = new String[company.size()];
array4 = new String[date.size()];
array5 = new String[imageurl.size()];


for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
    array1[i] = qrcodelist.get(i);
    array2[i] = name.get(i);
    array3[i] = company.get(i);
    array4[i] = date.get(i);
    array5[i] = imageurl.get(i);

}
```

I thought to implement the same using `HashMap` but was not sure on how to do it.

I request you to give me a logic to implement this task or any sample code.

Comment: so if you sort an array, each array is sorted the same way as the other? I would object that your data structure is strange. I'd rather have an object with 5 String fields, and then an array of this object, and therefore it is easy to sort it according to a comparator or another

Comment: Strange data structures... Be careful with IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions in that for loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort multiple arrays in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164795/how-to-sort-multiple-arrays-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're suffering from "object denial". Your description isn't very clear, but it seems like you need a class with fields for "QR Code", "Name", etc. Once you have that, you have a single array full of instances of that class, instead of 5 separate arrays.

Now you can sort the array using a `Comparator` to put any ordering you want on it.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you to review your data structure. I mean it seams not to be a good idea to split the data in separate arrays. All the related data should be contained in one object.

Please check this question: [How to sort multiple arrays in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164795/how-to-sort-multiple-arrays-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand I guess you just want to sort an array, next time search for it. There is a good example here: [Android sort array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4980720/969325)

Search for words like java sort array comparable in order to get more on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an object to store all the data corresponding to each entity, put each object in a Collection or an Array and then sort them implementing Comparable interface:

```
public class MyData implements Comparable<MyData> {

private String qrcodelist;
private String  name;
private String  company;
private String  date;
private String  imageurl;

//more code...
}
```