# How do i sort a simple integer 2 dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a 2 dimensional array, that has dimensions of `myArray[x][3]`. I need to sort the array based upon `[x][0]`. I was using `Arrays.sort(myArray);`. That was working, however, the array at the time was a one dimension array of `myArray[x]`. Then I changed my mind and changed it into a 2 dimensional array. It is filled with integers from 1 to 9. I have searched for the clear method to sort 2 dimensional arrays, and cannot find the simple explanations. Please help.

Thanks;
Ice

Ok, here is the code:

```
public static void sortArray(int myArray[][]){
Arrays.sort(myArray, new Comparator<Integer[]>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Integer[] o1, Integer[] o2) {
        return o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]);
    }
});
```

Did that work?

OK, here is the problem. The sorted array starts out unsorted, like this:

```
3 - 0 - 0
4 - 0 - 1
5 - 0 - 2
6 - 0 - 3
3 - 0 - 4
```

The first column `[0][x]` is the value, the second column `[1][x]` is the array field count, and the last column `[2][x]` is the actual column number in the array. The overall method, takes a entire row from the original 2 dimensional array, and loads it into a 3-tall by x-wide array, then sorts the array based on the `[0][x]` column. Here is the result after the sort function now being called:

```
0 - 0 - 3
0 - 1 - 4
0 - 2 - 5
0 - 3 - 6
0 - 4 - 3
```

Somehow, the method I copied and pasted, is swapping out the numbers, seems like the sorting is wrong. Same `System.out.print` is being used on both outputs.

Comment: Do you want the entire 2-D array sorted as a whole, or do you want each row of the array sorted individually?

Comment: You mean that you want to sort the array column wise ?

Comment: I need the array to be sorted based upon column 0, keeping the columns bound together. The first column contains the value, the second column contains basically a x co-ordinate, the third column contains basically the y value, so, yes, they need to stay together. The first column is what needs to be sorted, from smallest to largest.

Comment: You can adapt the answer from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907683/sort-a-two-dimensional-array-based-on-one-column into your data type. It sorts on the first column.

Comment: ok, I will go look at that and see how it can be adapted.  Thanks

Comment: not that easy for me to understand how to adapt that...:(

Answer (score 3):

If I got it right:

```
    Integer[][] numbers = new Integer[][]{{7, 8, 9}, {1, 2, 3}};
    System.out.println("Before:");
    for(Integer[] row : numbers) {
        for(Integer num : row) {
            System.out.print(num);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    Arrays.sort(numbers, new Comparator<Integer[]>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer[] o1, Integer[] o2) {
            return o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]);
        }
    });
    System.out.println("After:");
    for(Integer[] row : numbers) {
        for(Integer num : row) {
            System.out.print(num);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Prints:

```
Before:
789
123
After:
123
789
```

**Update:**

This exactly what you need.

```
public static void sortArray(int myArray[][]) {
    Arrays.sort(myArray, new Comparator<int[]>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(o1[0]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2[0]));
        }

    });
}
```

**Update2:**

Sorting each row:

```
public static void sortEachRow(int myArray[][]) {
    for(int[] row : myArray) {
        Arrays.sort(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is what I have placed into a method, so that i can call it to make it work...`code`public static void sortArray(int myArray[][]){
    Arrays.sort(numbers, new Comparator<Integer[]>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer[] o1, Integer[] o2) {
            return o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]);
        }
    });
    
}`code`

Comment: @IceRegent: Update your post with method. Also, you forgot tell what problem you are having now.

Comment: I apologize, I am not finding how to update the post with method. The problem is, I am getting errors when I place that code into my method in my netbeans. the "Arrays.sort(numbers, new Comparator<Integer[]>(){", the word "numbers" is underlined, but, obviously, I replace it with my array name, myArray, and then the entire line of code gets underlined.

Comment: When I click the link edit, it just allows me to add or change the current comment, and I tried surrounding my code with the `code` keys, but it doesnt change anything.

Comment: @IceRegent: Not that __edit__, the __edit__ at the bottom part of your original post. It's right under, where you have written: "Thanks; Ice".

Comment: @IceRegent: See update. I added the method you need, you can copy it and it will work. Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked.

Comment: lol. You are too fast for me. I just saw your update, and copied and pasted it. Now I go back to my code, and my passing of the array to the method is not creating any errors. Sorry I replied before I saw your update. My entire code so far, is over 207 lines thus far, so I do not want to post the entire friggin code here, to bugger up the pages, lol. But now, I need to understand it, and verify that it is working, and the problem is, my second array is [3][x], whereas the first array was [x][3], so I need to sort on rows in one, and on columns in the other.

Comment: I need to keep the original x and y values associated with the data. I have an original array, with [x][x] size. I copy out a row at a time into another array, copying both the data in the cell, and the row and column number. I then need to sort the new array, keeping the row and column number associated with the data cell.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) 
{
    Integer[][] numbers = new Integer[][] {{7, 8, 9}, {1, 2, 3}};
    sortArray(numbers);
    for (Integer[] s : numbers) {
        System.out.println(s[0] + " " + s[1] + " " + s[2]);
    }
}

public static void sortArray(Integer myArray[][])
{ 
    Arrays.sort(myArray, new Comparator<Integer[]>()
    { 
            @Override 
            public int compare(Integer[] o1, Integer[] o2) 
            {
                    return o1[0].compareTo(o2[0]); 
            } 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Seems to give no errors, but when i try to pass my array from inside my other code, it underlines in red as in an error condition:    sortArray(myArray);

Comment: Not sure I understand. The parameter should be `numbers` not `myArray`. Or did you mean that `sortArray(numbers)` gives an error ?

Comment: No, in the first part, you are creating an array and filling it, then displaying it with your name of the array. I already have an array created, actually i am working with 3 different arrays, but i just need to sort one of them right now. The name of the array I need to sort, is called myRows. So, when I call the method sortArray, I need to pass the actual array of "myRows".

Comment: Are the arrays declared as `Integer` not `int`? The declaration for `sortArray` also has `Integer` as parameter.

Comment: the arrays are declared as int.

Comment: Declare it as `Integer`. It should work now. The errors are because of mismatch between `int` and `Integer`.