# Sorting String[][] unexpected output

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I want to sort my String[][] with respect to second column. I tried this

```
public static String[][] sorting_minn(String[][] list){ 
    double[] temp = new double[list.length];
    String[][] tempf = list;

    if(list[1][1]!=null){
    for(int i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
        if(list[i][2]==null){
            break;

        } else {
            temp[i]=Double.parseDouble(list[i][2]);


        }

    }

Arrays.sort(temp);

for(int f = 0; f<list.length-1;f++){
    for(int m = 0; m<list.length;m++){
        if(list[m][2]!=null && Double.parseDouble(list[m][2])==temp[f]){
             for(int n = 0; n<4; n++){
                 tempf[list.length-f-1][n]=list[m][n];

             }
        m = list.length;
            }
        }

    }
}
return tempf;

}
```

As an output I get this: [image: output] . I need suggestion on how to improve this code.

Comment: Could you add the desired output?

Comment: So that you are aware; the *second* column is located at index `[1]` **not** index `[2]`.

Comment: @NominSim I'm aware of that.

Comment: Already answered here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907683/sort-a-two-dimensional-array-based-on-one-column

Comment: @11684 the desired output would be basiacally the same table but with last three rows entries left null;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like:

```
        Arrays.sort(list, new Comparator<String[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
                String left = o1[1]!=null ? o1[1] : "";
                String right = o2[1]!=null ? o2[1] : "";
                return left.compareTo(right);
            }
        });
```

this treats nulls as empty strings, and exploits the fact that strings are comparable, although lexicographic. if you want the reverse order just do this instead:

```
right.compareTo(left)
```

if you want integer ordering you could parse an Integer out of both sides (Integer.MIN for null) and compare 2 Integers