# sort 2d String array in java -sort index element inside my array

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

Hi i need to sort array two Dimension in java but i need the sorting to be by index inside my array 
my array is

```
  String arr[][]={  {"joun","1525565","10"},
                           {"ALI","15256562","100"},
                           {"FATEH","1525534","20"}   };
```

I need to sort my array by index number two 
and the output is

```
   String arr[][]={ {"ALI","15256562","100"},
                       {"FATEH","1525534","20"},
                         {"joun","1525565","10"} };
```

my order must be 100 then 20 then 10

i tried to put this code in java put the problem the program get confused from the index 1 and two 
i used inside for loop 
 Arrays.sort(arr[i])

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846301/sorting-a-2d-string-array-in-java

Comment: if it's work with Arrays.sort   it will be better but i think it's not working with this method

Comment: Look at Peter Lawrey's answer for `Arrays.sort`in Java 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution with Comparator:

```
public class SortTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String arr[][]={  {"joun","1525565","10"},
                {"ALI","15256562","100"},
                {"FATEH","1525534","20"}   };

        Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<String[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
                return Integer.parseInt(o2[2]) - Integer.parseInt(o1[2]);
            }
        });

        for (String[] item : arr) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(item));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user44444 "it sort every thing" <- what do you mean?

Comment: i mean it sort the number  1525565 and 10

my array now is 
 {"joun","1525565","100"}, but now it's {"joun","1525565","10"}


array[0] was  {"joun","1525565","100"}

Comment: @user44444 in your initial example it is: {"joun","1525565","10"} sorted output of my code is: [ALI, 15256562, 100]
[FATEH, 1525534, 20]
[joun, 1525565, 10] where is the issue?

Comment: OK the problem was from me because my array is not the same what i wrote in the example but it similar 
 i edit some thing in your code and it's working for me now
your code is working  immediately with my example above  thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

In Java 8 you would write this to sort by index `2` for decreasing numeric order with

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparing(row -> -Long.parseLong(row[2])));
```

or

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparing((String[] row) -> Long.parseLong(row[2]))
                           .reversed());
```

---

For ascending order as a String rather than a number.

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparing(row -> row[2]));
```

This would order `10, 100, 20` but if you made longer strings before shorter ones.

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparing((String[] row) -> row[2].length()).reversed()
                           .thenComparing(row->row[2]));
```

This would give the order as `100, 10, 20`

BTW: I don't know why the first `row` needs the type given.

if you wanted to sort by number you could do

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparing(row -> Long.parseLong(row[2])));
```

This would put `10, 20, 100` in increasing order.

In Java 8 you can add an anonymous inner class to do the same thing.

Comment: what is row here ? is it the array name ? 
because i get an error

Comment: @user44444 are using using Java 8? `row` is the name of the nested array.  What error do you get?  This is using Java 8's lambdas and Streams API.

Comment: ok i changed my project to 8 and there is no error but the code is not working with me i wrote 

             Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparing(row -> row[2]));
             
             
             
             for (String[] item : arr) {
                 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(item));
             }
and i get the same last array

Comment: the error is 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Comparable<? super Comparable<? super U>>

Comment: @user44444 I tried three different ways to sort the numbers. ;) can explain the sort order you want. Is it decreasing numeric order?

Comment: it's not problem the order if reversed or not 
i dont care if it's 100 20 10 or 10 20 100

Comment: thanks for your help the code below is working with me :) thanks

Comment: @user44444 ok, see the first or last solution.

Comment: it mix the element :(

Comment: @user44444 what did you expect it to do? It should sort it as stated in the question.

Comment: can you do it with any way ? the way is not important 
the code above gave me an red line  error

Comment: @user44444 I tested it in my IDE and it was fine. Can you check you have entered it correctly?