# How to create multidimensional array with my objects in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, multidimensional-array

Could You tell me whether i can create multidimensional array  which is created with my objects in java?

In other words:

I have got this class:

```
public class ClosestObject {
public Double distance;
public String classes;

public ClosestObject() {
        this.distance=new Double(0);
        this.classes=new String("");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }   
}
```

And I want to create multidimensional array in another class in that way:

```
    ClosestObject[][] closestobj=new ClosestObject[query.length][learning_set.length];

    for(int i=0; i<query.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<learning_set.length;j++)
        {
            closestobj[i][j].distance=Math.abs(query[i]-learning_set[j][0]);
            closestobj[i][j].classes=classes[j][0];
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<closestobj.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<closestobj[i].length;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(closestobj[i][j].distance + " " + closestobj[i][j].classes);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunatelly I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at KNN.Find_closest_distance(KNN.java:60)
at KNN.main(KNN.java:37)
```

Could someone tell me where i made mistake. Thank You in advance :)

Comment: By default new array of objects is filled with `null`s (and null doesn't have any `distance` filed which is why you are getting NPE). So before you call `closestobj[i][j].distance=...` you need to first put new instances in that cell with `closestobj[i][j] = new  ClosestObject ()`.

Comment: Can you add Your comment as the answer because You are right and i want to give you "right answer" tag :)

Comment: It is common problem and it is already explained in one of answers from duplicate question (link is above your question - you may refresh your page to see it) so feel free to up-vote answer which explains it.

Comment: Thank you for your edit, but to me, your link is a general discussion of the NullPointerException and I have a specific case.

Comment: Yes, it is general discussion but it contains explanation and potential solution to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23852556/1393766. I may try to find better candidate for duplicate if you wish.

Comment: No, You are right they are simmilar :) I have got only one request. Could You tell me how can i sort that multidimensional array ? Because i have to sort it by "public Double distance" ? I will be very thankfull.

Comment: OK, my previous comment (now deleted but pointing to http://stackoverflow.com/q/4907683/1393766) could be based on false assumption. Could you explain how do you want to sort your array exactly?

Comment: Yeah, no problem. I am making my own implementation of kNN machine learning algorithm and I want to sort closestobj array by Double distance which is placed in ClosestObject class. In that case I don't know how to transport that to sorting function. Please tell me whether it is clear to You?

Comment: Not quite. Could you post link to simple example with of unsorted and sorted 2d array? Or lets say that we have 2d array like `[[8,5], [9,2]]`. Do you want to order elements in each row like `[[5,8], [2,9]]` or you want to sort all elements like `[[2,5], [8,9]]` (this will allow moving elements between rows).

Comment: Ok so let me show it on the example

Comment: I have got multidimensional array which contains objects. 
It looks like something like that :
[[1object, 2object,3object], [4object,5object, 6object]...]
1object.distance = 16.1;
1object.classes = rose ;
2object.distance =56.2;
2object.classes = another flower;
... 
I want to sort objects inside each row of my array by distance. Do you understand? :-)

Comment: OK so you only want to sort rows (first case of my example: `[[5,8], [2,9]]`). Are you familiar with `Arrays.sort(row, Comparator)` method?

Comment: I have tried that: Arrays.sort(closestobj[0]); but i get error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: ClosestObject cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
 at KNN.Find_closest_distance(KNN.java:72)
 at KNN.main(KNN.java:40)

Comment: @Pshemo I solve sorting by that:  `for(int k=0;k<query.length;k++)
  {
   Arrays.sort(closestobj[k], new Comparator<ClosestObject>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ClosestObject entry1, ClosestObject entry2) {
     ClosestObject time1 = entry1;
     // System.out.println(time1);
     ClosestObject time2 = entry2;
     // System.out.println(time2.distance);
     return time1.distance.compareTo(time2.distance);
    }
   });
  }`  thank You very much for Your help :)