# Sorting 2d Arrays containing Numbers and Strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an Inventory as shown below.

```
var arr1 = [
    [21, "Bowling Ball"],
    [2, "Dirty Sock"],
    [1, "Hair Pin"],
    [5, "Microphone"]
];
```

I want to sort the inventory alphabetically. I tried using a simple bubble sort technique to do it. But it shows an error-"wrappedCompareFn is not a function".

```
function sort(arr1){    
//console.log("works");
for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){      
  for(var j=0;j<arr1.length;j++){     
   // console.log(arr1[j][1].localeCompare(arr1[i][1]));
    if(arr1[j][1].localeCompare(arr1[i][1])<0){          
      var tmp=arr1[i][1];
      arr1[i][1]=arr1[j][1];
      arr1[j][1]=tmp;          
       }          
    }      
  }        
return arr1;
}
```

Is there a problem with my code?? Also is there a better way to sort multidimensional arrays with different types of objects??

Comment: This is not bubble sort. The initial value of the inner loop should be: `for (var j=i+1; ...`

Comment: Possible alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907683/sort-a-two-dimensional-array-based-on-one-column

Comment: you are not clear, you want to sort it by first column or second..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the build in method [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a custom callback.

> The `sort()` method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the array. The sort is not necessarily [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability). The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.

```js
var arr1 = [[1, "Hair Pin"], [21, "Bowling Ball"], [2, "Dirty Sock"], [5, "Microphone"]];

arr1.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[1].localeCompare(b[1]);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr1, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Just a few doubtss...What is a and b here. Is it two elements of the array in order??

Comment: a and b are elements of the outer array, for example, it compares `[21, "Bowling Ball"]` against `[2, "Dirty Sock"]`. for the result, you need to access the second element of the inner array with the index.