# firefox TypeError: wrappedCompareFn is not a function [duplicated]

Tags: firefox, reactjs, sass, webpack

My build is working in Chrome, Safari, and Opera but breaking in Firefox.
I'm using React, Webpack, and Sass.
The console error I get is: 
`TypeError: wrappedCompareFn is not a function bundle.js:39813:24`
and
`TypeError: node is null bundle.js:7865:1`
Below I've included my webpack file and the dependencies in my package.json.  Any help we be greatly appreciated.
Webpack:

```
    const path = require('path');
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
    const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

    module.exports = {
      context: __dirname,
      debug: true,
      devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
      entry: './client/src/App.jsx',
      output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, './client/public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
      },
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
      },
      externals: {
      },
      stats: {
        colors: true,
        reasons: true,
        chunks: false,
      },
      plugins: [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
        // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env': {
            NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
          },
        }),
      ],
      module: {
        preLoaders: [
          {
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node-modules/,
          },
        ],
        noParse: [
          /plotly\.js/,
        ],
        loaders: [
          {
            test: /\.styl$/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader',
          },
          {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader',
          },
          {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
          },
          {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json-loader',
          },
          {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|ico|ttf)$/i,
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      postcss: [autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] })],
      watch: false,
    };
```

package.json dependencies:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "bluebird": "^3.4.6",
        "classnames": "^2.2.5",
        "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
        "dotenv": "^2.0.0",
        "express": "^4.14.0",
        "http-status-codes": "^1.0.6",
        "koa": "^1.2.4",
        "koa-add-trailing-slashes": "^1.1.0",
        "koa-basic-auth": "^1.1.2",
        "koa-jwt": "^1.2.0",
        "koa-mount": "^1.3.0",
        "koa-route": "^2.4.2",
        "koa-static": "^2.0.0",
        "material-ui": "^0.16.2",
        "materialize-css": "^0.97.8",
        "moment": "^2.15.2",
        "pm2": "^2.1.6",
        "react": "^15.4.0",
        "react-dom": "^15.4.0",
        "react-materialize": "^0.17.0",
        "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
        "react-router": "^3.0.0",
        "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.0",
        "react-tooltip": "^3.2.2",
        "redux": "^3.6.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "autofixture": "^0.1.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^6.5.4",
        "babel-core": "^6.18.0",
        "babel-eslint": "^6.1.2",
        "babel-jest": "^16.0.0",
        "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
        "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
        "babel-register": "^6.18.0",
        "bluebird": "^3.4.6",
        "chai": "^3.5.0",
        "child_process": "^1.0.2",
        "co-supertest": "0.0.10",
        "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
        "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
        "enzyme": "^2.5.1",
        "eslint": "^3.9.1",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^12.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.0.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.2.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.4.1",
        "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "gulp-batch": "^1.0.5",
        "gulp-debug": "^2.1.2",
        "gulp-eslint": "^3.0.1",
        "gulp-exit": "0.0.2",
        "gulp-jest": "^0.6.0",
        "gulp-mocha": "^3.0.1",
        "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
        "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
        "gulp-run": "^1.7.1",
        "gulp-tap": "^0.1.3",
        "gulp-testcafe": "^0.9.0",
        "gulp-watch": "^4.3.11",
        "gulp-webserver": "^0.9.1",
        "jest": "^16.0.2",
        "jquery": "^3.1.1",
        "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
        "live-server": "^1.1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.16.6",
        "materialize-css": "^0.97.8",
        "mocha": "^3.1.2",
        "node-materialize": "^1.1.1",
        "node-sass": "^3.11.2",
        "postcss-loader": "^1.2.1",
        "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "^15.4.0",
        "request-promise": "^4.1.1",
        "require-dir": "^0.3.1",
        "sass": "^0.5.0",
        "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
        "sass-rem": "^1.2.3",
        "sinon": "^1.17.6",
        "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
        "stylus": "^0.54.5",
        "stylus-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "supertest": "^2.0.1",
        "supertest-koa-agent": "^0.3.0",
        "testcafe": "^0.9.0",
        "webpack": "^1.13.3",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.1.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
      },
      "jest": {
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
          "js",
          "jsx"
        ],
        "moduleNameMapper": {
          "^.+\\.(css|styl|scss)$": "<rootDir>/test/mocks/styleMock.js",
          "^.+\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg)$": "<rootDir>/test/mocks/fileMock.js"
        },
        "moduleDirectories": [
          "node_modules"
        ],
        "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
        "testPathDirs": [
          "test/ui"
        ],
        "testRegex": ".*-tests\\.(js|jsx)$"
      }
    }
```

Link to [post possible duplicated from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132853/sorting-2d-arrays-containing-numbers-and-strings)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting 2d Arrays containing Numbers and Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132853/sorting-2d-arrays-containing-numbers-and-strings)